# Image format in android

Tags: android

Which is the image format used in Android apps?

Answer (score 6):

> Android supports bitmap resource files in a few different formats:
>   png (preferred), jpg (acceptable), gif (discouraged).

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/available-resources.html

Answer (score 0):

Android supports JPEG ,GIF, BMP, PNG, WebP image formats. More details [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html).